# How do I theme a link?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7 this was possible.

```
$link = array(
  '#type'  => 'link',
  '#title' => t('My Title'),
  '#href'  => 'node/1',
);
drupal_render($link);
```

But I've tried this with Drupal 8, and it does not output anything.

```
$link = array(
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => t('test'),
  '#url' => 'node/1',
);
drupal_render($link);
```

Is there a way I can render a link without having to call the [Link plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x) directly, or create my own theme function?

I'm theming a field group formatter, which must output a render array.
The use of [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/render/8.2.x) is deprecated and should not be called directly; I'm using it here to make my example clearer.

Comment: Actually this should work. What means does not output anything ?
Where do you print this rendered HTML ?? drupal_render() is deprecated.
Call the RenderService directly: \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($elements, $is_recursive_call) Just to generate the link you could also use: Link::fromTextAndUrl($text, Url $url) See the [link class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x).

Comment: What do you want to theme ??

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as stated I do not want to call the Link plugin directly.  I've updated my question with a bit more background info to understand my scenario.

Comment: Have added info about what I'm theming to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem with your Drupal 8 code is that '#url' needs a URL object.

#### External URL

```
'#url' => Url::fromUri('https://www.drupal.org'),
```

#### Internal URL from a route

```
'#url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1]),
```

In Drupal 8 you are not supposed to render yourself. When porting code from Drupal 7, remove all rendering and return only render arrays.

Comment: Great thanks, this works!  Yes I'm not ```drupal_render()``` directly, it was just for the example.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can also use [`\Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AfromTextAndUrl/8.2.x) or [`\Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/8.2.x).

Twig can print that as-is, you can also get a render array by calling [`\Drupal\Core\Link::toRenderable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AtoRenderable/8.2.x). The resulting render array is the same then as building it from hand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to render a link in Drupal 8 with a custom class.  It's a little odd, but the options are passed into the URL, not the link function.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$options = array('attributes' => array('class' => 'my-custom-class'));
$url = Url::fromUri('http://www.example.com', $options);
$markup = \Drupal::l(t('Link Text Goes Here!'), $url);
```

This is useful in a field formatter, that expects markup returned.  If you are doing this elsewhere, it's best to convert it to a link render array item.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$options = array('attributes' => array('class' => 'my-custom-class'));
$build['examples_link'] = [
  '#title' => t('Link Text Goes Here!'),
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => Url::fromUri('http://www.example.com', $options)
];
```