# How to build render array with node title linked to node for a list of nodes

Tags: 8

I have a paragraph type to output a list of content. The editor can set different options, one of them is to show the list as teasers or just node titles linked to node. The corresponding part in code looks like:

```
    if ($teaser_display) {
      $value = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, 'teaser');
    }
    else {
      $value = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewField($node->get('title'), ['link' => true, 'type' => 'entity_reference_label']);
    }
```

Is there a way to build the render array for titel field linked to the node without creating a dedicated view mode and without rendering the markup directly? I thought it should somehow work to use the method [viewField()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityViewBuilderInterface%3A%3AviewField/8.2.x) as $display_options can either be a view mode or an array with display options.

Comment: This formatter is for an entity reference field, so you can use it only on the field in the paragraph type where you reference the node.

Comment: Is there a way/formatter to theme the title as link? Or doesn't it work as title is a basefield an does not have a formatter. I was wrong on view mode, it's also not possible without modifying the template.

Comment: 1) As said in the comment before, it is possible when you view `$paragraph->field_reference` with `entity_reference_label`. 2) Yes, now the title is not configurable in view modes and hardcoded in the node template, but this is going to change. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2353867

Comment: I think this ticket can be closed as it is now just about [How do I theme a link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201881/how-do-i-theme-a-link).

Comment: Thanks for linking the d.o.. I wanted to link it too, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. You are rendering this in a paragraph? Then you can't simply build the link like this without including the cache tag `'#cache' => ['tags' => $node->getCacheTags()],`, which btw. the field formatter on the paragraph field would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93028/discussion-between-lars-and-4k4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @4k4 I used the entity reference field formatter, which does not apply here. Theming as link, as answered in [How do I theme a link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201881/how-do-i-theme-a-link) does the job:

```
if ($teaser_display) {
  $value = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, 'teaser');
}
else {
  $value = [
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => $node->label(),
    '#url' => $node->toUrl(),
    '#cache' => ['tags' => $node->getCacheTags()],
  ];
}
```